# Calculating the angle between the clock's hour and minute hands with unit testing

Tags: beginner, php, datetime, unit-testing

I am learning PHP OOP and unit testing so I made a code using OOP and TDD approach where it calculates the degree of and angle betwee the clock's hour and minute hands.

I would like to know:

1. Is the structure of my object class good? If not, what is the better approach?
2. I know my test has covered the codes that need to be tested but is there anything I need to improve when it comes to unit testing?

_

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php 

namespace App;

Class ClockAngle
{
    const FULL_ROTATION_DEGREES = 360;
    const HALF_ROTATION_DEGREES = 180;
    const HOUR_HAND_DEGREE_ROTATION_PER_MINUTES = 0.5;
    const MINUTE_HAND_DEGREE_ROTATION_PER_MINUTES = 6;
    const ONE_HOUR_IN_MINUTES = 60;

    private $hour;
    private $minute;

    public function getAngleBetweenClockHands($time) { 
        $this->hour    = explode(':', $time)[0];
        $this->minute  = explode(':', $time)[1];

        return $this->calculateAngleBetweenHands();
    }

    private function angleBetweenTwelveAndHourHand() {
        return self::HOUR_HAND_DEGREE_ROTATION_PER_MINUTES * (self::ONE_HOUR_IN_MINUTES * $this->hour + $this->minute);
    }

    private function angleBetweenTwelveAndMinuteHand() {
        return self::MINUTE_HAND_DEGREE_ROTATION_PER_MINUTES * $this->minute;
    }

    private function calculateAngleBetweenHands() {
        $angle = abs($this->angleBetweenTwelveAndHourHand() - $this->angleBetweenTwelveAndMinuteHand());

        if ($this->isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation($angle)) {
            return self::FULL_ROTATION_DEGREES - $angle;
        }

        return $angle;
    }

    private function isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation($angle) {
        return $angle > self::HALF_ROTATION_DEGREES;
    }
}
```

Test Code

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php 

namespace App\Test;
use App\ClockAngle;

Class ClockAngleTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    public function setUp() {
        $this->clockAngle = new ClockAngle();
        $this->reflector  = new \ReflectionClass($this->clockAngle);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider timeInputs
     */
    public function test_it_can_get_angle_degree_between_clock_hands($input, $expected, $message) {
        $angle = $this->clockAngle->getAngleBetweenClockHands($input);
        $this->assertEquals($angle, $expected, $message);
    }

    public function timeInputs() {
        return array(
            '1:00'  => array('1:00',  30,    'The angle between 1 and 00 is 30'),
            '1:15'  => array('1:15',  52.5,  'The angle between 1 and 15 is 52.5'),
            '2:15'  => array('2:15',  22.5,  'The angle between 2 and 15 is 22.5'),
            '2:20'  => array('2:20',  50,    'The angle between 2 and 20 is 50'),
            '2:59'  => array('2:59',  95.5,  'The angle between 2 and 59 is 95.5'),
            '3:15'  => array('3:15',  7.5,   'The angle between 3 and 15 is 7.5'),
            '7:15'  => array('7:15',  127.5, 'The angle between 7 and 15 is 127.5'),
            '10:16' => array('10:16', 148,   'The angle between 10 and 16 is 148'),
            '6:30'  => array('6:30',   15,   'The angle between 6 and 30 is 15'),
        );
    }

    public function test_hour_hand_is_at_10_and_angle_degree_should_be_300() {
        $expected = 300;
        $hour = 10;
        $minute = 0;

        $this->assertHourHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected);
    }

    public function test_hour_hand_is_at_1_and_angle_degree_should_be_30() {
        $expected = 30;
        $hour = 1;
        $minute = 0;

        $this->assertHourHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected);
    }

    public function test_hour_hand_is_at_5_and_angle_degree_should_be_150() {
        $expected = 150;
        $hour = 5;
        $minute = 0;

        $this->assertHourHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected);
    }

    public function test_minute_hand_is_at_40_and_angle_degree_should_be_240() {
        $expected = 240;
        $hour = 0;
        $minute = 40;

        $this->assertMinuteHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected);
    }

    public function test_minute_hand_is_at_33_and_angle_degree_should_be_198() {
        $expected = 198;
        $hour = 0;
        $minute = 33;

        $this->assertMinuteHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected);
    }

    public function test_minute_hand_is_at_5_and_angle_degree_should_be_90() {
        $expected = 90;
        $hour = 0;
        $minute = 15;

        $this->assertMinuteHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected);
    }

    public function test_calculate_angle_degree_between_hour_hand_is_at_1_and_minute_hand_is_at_12_in_half_rotation() {
        $expected = 36;
        $hour = 1;
        $minute = 12;

        $this->setHourAndMinuteProperty($hour, $minute);
        $calculateAngleBetweenHands = $this->getPrivateMethod('calculateAngleBetweenHands');
        $result = $calculateAngleBetweenHands->invokeArgs($this->clockAngle, array());

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result); 
    }

    public function test_calculate_angle_degree_between_hour_hand_is_at_1_and_minute_hand_is_at_45_in_full_rotation() {
        $expected = 142.5;
        $hour = 1;
        $minute = 45;

        $this->setHourAndMinuteProperty($hour, $minute);
        $calculateAngleBetweenHands = $this->getPrivateMethod('calculateAngleBetweenHands');
        $result = $calculateAngleBetweenHands->invokeArgs($this->clockAngle, array());

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result); 
    }

    public function test_when_angle_is_less_than_half_rotation() {
        $angle = 160;

        $isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation = $this->getPrivateMethod('isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation');
        $result = $isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation->invokeArgs($this->clockAngle, array($angle));
        $this->assertFalse($result);
    }

    public function test_when_angle_is_greater_than_half_rotation() {
        $angle = 190;

        $isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation = $this->getPrivateMethod('isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation');
        $result = $isAngleMoreThanHalfRotation->invokeArgs($this->clockAngle, array($angle));
        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }

    private function assertHourHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected) {
        $this->setHourAndMinuteProperty($hour, $minute);
        $angleBetweenTwelveAndHourHand = $this->getPrivateMethod('angleBetweenTwelveAndHourHand');
        $result = $angleBetweenTwelveAndHourHand->invokeArgs($this->clockAngle, array());
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }

    private function assertMinuteHandAngleDegree($hour, $minute, $expected) {
        $this->setHourAndMinuteProperty($hour, $minute);
        $angleBetweenTwelveAndMinuteHand = $this->getPrivateMethod('angleBetweenTwelveAndMinuteHand');
        $result = $angleBetweenTwelveAndMinuteHand->invokeArgs($this->clockAngle, array());
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }

    private function setHourAndMinuteProperty($hour, $minute) {
        $minute_ = $minute;
        $hour_ = $hour;

        $minute = $this->reflector->getProperty('minute');
        $minute->setAccessible(true);
        $minute->setValue($this->clockAngle, $minute_);

        $hour = $this->reflector->getProperty('hour');
        $hour->setAccessible(true);
        $hour->setValue($this->clockAngle, $hour_);
    }

    private function getPrivateMethod($methodName) {
        $method = $this->reflector->getMethod($methodName);
        $method->setAccessible(true);

        return $method;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the code is doing. Just posting it without any comments is off-topic and considered as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @t3chb0t, sorry. Updated it :)

Comment: The title also needs to be fixed - it's too general. It should be about what the code is doing e.g. _Calculating the angle between the clock's hour and minute hands_ or something similar.

Comment: @t3chb0t please see the update.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not an improvement. I'll set _my_ title ;-]

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be caught in between making a decision on whether this should be a concrete class or a class to be used statically.  If concrete as currently designed, I don't understand why you wouldn't just pass the time to the constructor and set the angle as a property which can be read vs. recalculatated every time via a method call.

If you truly want to treat these methods in essence as static methods like you are currently doing, then consider making these methods static and don't store state.

---

I think you may have gone a bit overboard in making granular methods here for such a simple calculation.  This is reflected in your unit tests where you are trying to do the right thing to test each individual method, but end up exercising the same lines of code over and over again.

None of these more granular methods are ever exercised outside the context of being called downstream from `getAngleBetweenClockHands()` and will always be called exactly in the same order and exactly the same number of times regardless of input value.  This seems like breaking apart a logically monolithic operation just for the sake of trying to get "methods that do only one thing".  There are only like 10 lines of logic in this whole class, do they really need to be broken apart?

---

> ```
> public function getAngleBetweenClockHands($time) { 
>     $this->hour    = explode(':', $time)[0];
>     $this->minute  = explode(':', $time)[1];
>
>     return $this->calculateAngleBetweenHands();
> }
> ```

You may consider passing DateTime object to this method instead of just a string.  That gives you the ability to enforce the parameter type via typehint.  As it stands right now, you have nothing here to validate that a proper string format is passed.

There is no reason to `explode()` twice here.  Just explode once and work with the resulting array.

If wanting to work with concrete objects this logic should be in the constructor so that you can enforce that the object gets set up in proper state.

How does this method handle AM/PM?  Is it using 24 hour clock?

Your test data only reflect values < 12:00, it seems as if you are missing coverage here.

---

Be consistent in using either camelCase or snake_case in your method names. Don't mix them in the same code section like you are doing in your unit tests.

---

I don't understand in your unit tests why you have one method using a data provider but then a slew of additional test methods that just test different values which could probably be covered in the method using the data provider.

---

Your tests are all happy path.  You are testing no edge cases at all (i.e. bad input).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Mike. You are right when you said _This seems like breaking apart a logically monolithic operation just for the sake of trying to get "methods that do only one thing"._ I always thought that by doing so it would make my code more readable.

Comment: @aomanansala Other than the comment about mixing cases, I find your code to be very easy to read from a style standpoint. I don't think that 10 or so lines of code is too much for one method. There is a fine line between getting too granular in your method definitions, but I would err on the site of the way you did it. Just don't be afraid to refactor into fewer methods if you get into writing unit tests and are finding yourself writing a lot of extra code to test them all.

Comment: Is it necessary to test a method if it has the correct type passed to it in TDD? or the type checking should only be within the method being tested?

Comment: @aomanansala Yes. I would test it.  Think of your unit tests as a contract.  Your code must fulfill that contract.  So even if you type-hinted that a `DateTime` for example is passed as a parameter, it would be good to have a test where you pass a non-`DateTime` value to verify that an exception is thrown.  If not doing type-hinting, then it is even more important to test that the method correctly validates the input.  Like in your example, that a properly formatted time string is sent.

Comment: how will you create a test to verify a passed parameter has the correct type? I actually created a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41736492/check-passed-arguments-data-type-through-phpunit and I'm kind of stuck on that part.

Comment: @aomanansala Typically, one would assert that an exception is thrown on bad input, assuming of course the code under test is made to throw an exception in such a case.